# How to create percentage range in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have below-mentioned dataframe in R.

```
ID      ValueDiff  GradeDiff
I-1     -96.67%   -180%
I-2     -96.67%   -20%
I-3      Outlier   Outlier
I-4      0%        0%
I-5      50%       33.33%
```

I want to create the percentage range based on `ValueDiff` and `GradeDiff` column. Like `(-0.01% to -50.0%)`, `(-50.01% to -100.0%)`, `(0.01% to 50%)`, `(50.01% to 100%) and` 100%+`. For example if` ValueDiff`value is`-96.67%`then it will fall in`(-50.01% to -100.0%)`, In case if the value in` ValueDiff`or`GradeDiff`are 0% then in range keep it as 'Constant' and wherever its mentioned as`Outlier` carry forward the same value in %Range column.

Required Output <-

```
ID      ValueDiff  GradeDiff  %RngValue              %RngGrade
I-1     -96.67%    -180%      (-50.0% to -100.0%)    (-100.0+)
I-2     -96.67%    -20%       (-50.0% to -100.0%)    (-0.01% to -50.0%)
I-3      Outlier    Outlier   Outlier                Outlier
I-4      0%         0%        Constant               Constant
I-5      50%        33.33%    (0.01% to 50.0%)       (-0.01% to -50.0%)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `parse_number` to extract the number from `ValueDiff` and `GradeDiff` columns and with `case_when` assign the groups.

```
library(dplyr)
library(readr)

df %>%
  mutate(value = parse_number(ValueDiff), 
         grade = parse_number(GradeDiff),
         across(c(value, grade), ~case_when(. == 0 ~ 'Constant', 
                              is.na(.) ~ 'Outlier',
                              . < -100 ~ '(-100.0+)', 
                              . < -50 & . > -100 ~ '(-50.01% to -100.0%)', 
                              . < 0 & . >= -50 ~ '(-0.01% to -50.0%)', 
                              . > 0 & . <= 50 ~ '(0.01% to 50.0%)', 
                              . > 50 & . < 100 ~ '(50.01% to 100.0%)'
                              ), .names = 'Rng_{col}')) %>%
  suppressWarnings()

#   ID ValueDiff GradeDiff  value   grade            Rng_value          Rng_grade
#1 I-1   -96.67%     -180% -96.67 -180.00 (-50.01% to -100.0%)          (-100.0+)
#2 I-2   -96.67%      -20% -96.67  -20.00 (-50.01% to -100.0%) (-0.01% to -50.0%)
#3 I-3   Outlier   Outlier     NA      NA              Outlier            Outlier
#4 I-4        0%        0%   0.00    0.00             Constant           Constant
#5 I-5       50%    33.33%  50.00   33.33     (0.01% to 50.0%)   (0.01% to 50.0%)
```

Comment: This answer is almost enough to make me want to learn tidyverse. Most of the tidyverse code I see on SO looks less efficient and less clear than what I could do with base R, but this is simply amazing in its elegance.

Answer (score 0):

A base R solution is

```r
pct_grp <- function(x, eps = .Machine$double.eps){
  out <- suppressWarnings(as.numeric(gsub("%", "", x))) |>
    cut(c(-Inf, -100, -50, -eps, eps, 50, 100, Inf),
        c("<-100%", "(-100%, -50%]", "(-50%, 0%)", "Constant", "(0%, 50%]",
          "(50%, 100%]", ">100%"))
  replace(as.character(out), is.na(out), "Outlier")
}

transform(dat, RngValue = pct_grp(ValueDiff), RngGrade = pct_grp(GradeDiff))
#R>    ID ValueDiff GradeDiff      RngValue   RngGrade
#R> 1 I-1   -96.67%     -180% (-100%, -50%]     <-100%
#R> 2 I-2   -96.67%      -20% (-100%, -50%] (-50%, 0%)
#R> 3 I-3   Outlier   Outlier       Outlier    Outlier
#R> 4 I-4        0%        0%      Constant   Constant
#R> 5 I-5       50%    33.33%     (0%, 50%]  (0%, 50%]
```

It works in R 4.1.0 or greater. Otherwise you have to use a function like

```r
pct_grp <- function(x, eps = .Machine$double.eps){
  out <- suppressWarnings(as.numeric(gsub("%", "", x)))
  out <- cut(out, c(-Inf, -100, -50, -eps, eps, 50, 100, Inf),
             c("<-100%", "(-100%, -50%]", "(-50%, 0%)", "Constant", "(0%, 50%]",
             "(50%, 100%]", ">100%"))
  replace(as.character(out), is.na(out), "Outlier")
}
```

I changed from `(## to ##)` to `(##,##]` to be more explicit about the limits. The data is assigned as follows

```r
dat <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "
  ID      ValueDiff  GradeDiff
  I-1     -96.67%   -180%
  I-2     -96.67%   -20%
  I-3      Outlier   Outlier
  I-4      0%        0%
  I-5      50%       33.33%")
```